# How: Move Selected Text To Left on Mac

Tags: macos, key, shortcut

In the world of "everyone else" you use tab to move text to the right and shift+tab to move it to the left.

How is this done on Mac? Specifically, selected text.

I searched this phrase and it seems the phrase doesn't exist in the universe if you put the word "mac" with it.

Comment: It depend of the text editor and this question would be better on [Apple.se]

Comment: It does, and sorry for that lack of oversight. This is in Eclipse Keppler, and I just noticed that this works in the editor ok but if you open a task list (Window - Show View - Task List) and then try to shift+tab selected text in that it does not work. It deletes the text. So I am figuring now that it is a missing feature in Eclipse for this instance.

Answer (score 0):

After further review, this works in some editors and not in others on Mac. It will also work in some edit windows of a program but not in other edit windows of the same program. This could be a bug or by design. That is for the app developers to decide I presume.